# Find all pairs (x, y) in a sorted array so that x + y < z

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

This is an interview question. Given a sorted integer array and number z find all pairs (x, y) in the array so that x + y < z. Can it be done better than O(n^2)?

P.S. I know that we can find all pairs (x, y | x + y == z) in O(N).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot necessarily find all such pairs in O(n) time, because there might be O(n<sup>2</sup>) pairs of values that have this property.  In general, an algorithm can't take any less time to run than the number of values that it produces.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While I completely agree with your observation, see my comment regarding our ability to define the output "format" ourselves.

Answer (score 5):

In generate, no it can't. Consider the case where `x + y < z` for all `x`, `y` in the array. You have to touch (e.g. display) all of the `n(n - 1)/2` possible pairs in the set. This is fundamentally O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

If you are asked to output all pairs that satisfy that property, I don't think there is anything better than O(N^2) since there can be O(N^2) pairs in the output.

But this is also true for x + y = z, for which you claim there is a O(N) solution - so I might be missing something.

I suspect the original question asked for the number of pairs. In that case, it can be done in O(N log(N)). For each element x find out y = z - x and do a binary search for y in the array. The position of y gives the number of pairs that can be formed with that particular value of x. Summing this over all values in the array gives you the answer. There are N values and finding the number if pairs for each takes O(log(N)) (binary search), so the whole thing is O(N log(N)).

Answer (score 1):

You can *find* them in O(N), if you add the additional constraint that each element is unique.

After finding all of the x+y==z pairs, you know that for every x and y that satisfies that condition, every x or y (choose one) that is at a lower index than its pair satisfies the x+y < z condition.

Actually selecting these and outputting them would take O(n^2), but in a sense, the x+y==z pairs are a compressed form of the answer, together with the input.

(You can preprocess the input to a form where each element is unique, together with a counter for number of occurrences.  This would take O(N) time.  You can generalize this solution to unsorted arrays, increasing the time to O(nlogn).)

The justification for saying that finding the pairs in under the time linearly proportional to the size of the solution: Suppose the question is "what are the integers that are between 0 and the given input K"?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a **sorted** integer array, you could use the **Binary search algorithm**, so the best is `O(N)`, and the worst is `O(N*logN)`,  the average case is also `O(N*logN)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and for every element that little than z, use binary-search - total O(NlogN).

Total run-time : O(|P| + NlogN), where P is the resulting pairs.

Answer (score 0):

There actually exists an O(nlogn) solution to this question.
What I would do (after checking first if I'm allowed to do that) is to define the output format of my algorithm/function.

I would define it as a sequence of elements (S,T). S - Position of element in the array (or its value). T - Position of the sub-array [0,T]. So for example, if T=3, it means that element S combined with elements 0,1,2 and 3 satisfy the desired condition.

The total result of this is O(nlogn) run time, and O(n) memory.